# Пропажа Handle [СИ]

Tags: c, winapi, процесс, sendmessage, handle

Использую CreateProcess.

```
if (CreateProcess(
    "TreeSer.exe",      // имя исполняемого модуля
     NULL,              // командная строка
     NULL, NULL,        // SDs
     true,             // дескриптор параметра наследования
     CREATE_NO_WINDOW,  // флажки создания
     NULL,              // новый блок конфигурации
     NULL,              // имя текущего каталога
     &StartupInfo,      // информация предустановки
     &ProcessInfo)      // информация о процессе
     == false){
      printf("ERROR!!!");
      if (PauseOnExit == true) system("pause");
      return 41;
     }
```

Далее, по идее хэндл получен в ProcessInfo.hProcess.

```
if (WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 1000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT){
         return 41;
        }
```

Но, как оказалось - нефига

И отправка SendMessage тоже не доходит:

```
SendMessage(ProcessInfo.hProcess, WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM) STARTTREE, NULL);
```

Код TreSer.exe:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

// STD  библиотеки и заголовки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Windows библиотеки и заголовки
#include <windows.h>

// Пределы переменных
#include <limits.h>

// Работа со строками
#include <String.h>


enum TreeTCommands {
    STARTTREE, // Создание дерева-потока
        STOPTREE, // Удаление дерева-потока
        ADDTREE, // Добавление элемента в дерево
        GETMAXTREE, // Найти максимальный элемент
        GETMINTREE, // Найти минимальный элемент
        PRINTMETREE, // Печать дерева
        DELTREE // Удаление элемента из дерева
    };

// Структура листа дерева
struct TreeLeaf {
    int value;
    int LChild; // В нулевой ячейке выступает в роли кол-ва элементов
    int RChild;
};

    char *buf;
    FILE *file;

// Рекурсии
void PrintTree(struct TreeLeaf*, int, int); // Печать дерева
int SuccTree(struct TreeLeaf*, int, int);
// Поиск следующего за удаляемым элемента
struct TreeLeaf* DeleteFromTree(struct TreeLeaf*, int, int);
// Удаление из дерева

DWORD WINAPI TreeThreadF(LPVOID);

int main() {

    // Переменные
    bool exitBB = false; // Отвечает за сообщение выхода
    MSG msg; // сообщение
    struct TreeLeaf* Tree = NULL; // дерево
    int curleaf, prleaf; // текущий лист, предыдущий лист
    bool findplace; // найдено ли место?




    while (exitBB == false) {
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        file = fopen("answr.txt", "w");
        if (WM_COMMAND == msg.message) {
            switch (msg.wParam) {
            case STARTTREE:
                // Инициализация дерева
                if (Tree == NULL) {
                    Tree = (struct TreeLeaf*)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeLeaf));
                    if (Tree == NULL)
                        return 41; // Если что-то с RAM
                    Tree[0].LChild = 0; // Изначально элементо нет
                }
                break;
            case STOPTREE:
                free(Tree);
                break;

            case DELTREE:
                Tree = DeleteFromTree(Tree, 1, msg.lParam);
                break;
            ...
            default:
                printf("Unknown command\n");
                break;
            }

        }

        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ProcessInfo.hProcess содержит какой-то левый хэндл или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Для тех, кто не понял вопрос: Как получить хэндл запущенного процесса и в чем я ошибся?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить букву A : `CreateProcessA`

Comment: "Но, как оказалось - нефига" - что означает эта фраза? Что лежит в `ProcessInfo.hProcess` после вызова `CreateProcess`? Как вы инициализируете `StartupInfo`?

Comment: ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));

Comment: StartupInfo.cb = sizeof (STARTUPINFO);

Comment: @AnT Так вроде...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хендл процесса. Получен он у вас правильно (его возвращает `CreateProcess` в `PROCESS_INFORMATION`) но дальше вы с ним делаете что-то непонятное. Вызов `WaitForSingleObject` ждет завершения процесса, после этого вызова хендл перестает быть валидным, поскольку процесс завершился. В вашем случае вы либо дождетесь что процесс завершится, либо продолжите выполнение через 1000мсек. Чего вы хотели этим вызовом добиться? Ждать завершения процесса или просто задержать выполнение на 1 секунду?

И еще: не путайте хендл потока с хендлом процесса. Это разные вещи, и `PROCESS_INFORMATION` возвращает оба.

---

SendMessage. Эта функция у вас с ошибкой, так что неудивительно, что сообщение никуда не доходит. Первый аргумент у нее должен хендлом окна, а не процесса! То есть вы посылаете сообщение несуществующему окну.

Можно послать сообщение потоку, а не конкретному окну, но `SendMessage` этого делать не умеет. Причем именно потоку, а не процессу! Процесс не является исполняемой сущностью, упрощенно говоря, это просто контейнер.

Послать сообщение потоку можно функцией `PostThreadMessage` (заметьте, что там требуется указать не хендл потока, а ID потока). Проблема однако в том, что в отличие от функций `Send*`, функции `Post*` выполняются асинхронно, то есть они не могут возвращать значение. Они возвращают управление сразу, как только ставят сообщение в очередь потока, и возвращаемый результат у них `BOOL` (успешно/ошибка).

Если вам нужно вернуть результат, то вам придется использовать функцию из семейства `SendMessage`. Создается невидимое окно в получателе с известным именем класса и заголовком, отправитель его находит функцией FindWindow, и обработка происходит в не в цикле потока, а в оконной процедуре.

Comment: Это вы что-то путаете, `ProcessInfo.hProcess` это хендл процесса (см. [_PROCESS_INFORMATION structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-_process_information)). Плюс, `WaitForSingleObject` ждёт двух событий - или изменения состояния (завершения процесса), или таймаута 1 сек.

Comment: @zed - да, невнимательно посмотрел. А что это меняет? Посылка сообщения на хендл процесса операция еще более бессмысленная. Да, в `WaitForSingleObject` указан таймаут - и что от этого изменилось конкретно? Ну если вы так уж настаиваете на академической точности формулировок, то я поправлю ответ.

Comment: Обратите внимание еще на CREATE_NO_WINDOW,  // флажки создания

Comment: Если основное окно можно найти через FindWindow то как найти хэндл окна у безоконного приложения. Наверное никак...
Есть ли идеи как тогда лучше сделать межпроцессорное взаимодействие? Желательно с примером или ссылкой на пример. Спасибо!

Comment: @freim см. выше

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, даже если вашему приложению не нужно окно, ничто не мешает ему создать фиктивное невидимое окно нулевого размера. Именно так и поступают, когда у приложения нет окна, а сообщения обрабатывать нужно.

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, можно и без окна, но это будет сильно сложнее. По моему мнению, удобнее всего тут будет использовать [именованные каналы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/named-pipes). Там же и примеры использования есть.

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, Что касается флага CREATE_NO_WINDOW, он всего лишь значит, что не нужно создавать консольное окно при старте. Он никак не мешает приложению создавать свои окна.

Comment: @freim, А как тогда искать окно безоконно запущенного консольного приложения

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, Какая разница как оно было запущено? Консольное окно тут вообще никаким боком. Если программа создала окно после запуска, значит окно есть и его можно найти. И вообще, зачем вы программу делаете как консольное приложение если вам консольное окно не нужно? Надо, кстати, заканчивать с этим обсуждением, уже в чат выталкивают.